# USB-C charging cable for Nintendo Switch

Tags: switches, charger, adapter, usb-c

I am trying to change a broken USB-c charger connector for a nintendo switch by changing the male end connector.  The charger cable has 5 wires 2 red(Vbus) 2 Black (GND) and a small white cable that was connected to the PCB board labeled B-side.  I have the images attached the Vbus and GND are basic, however I am not sure what the white cable is for and how to find a correct replacement connector to refurbish this adapter.  Any help would be appreciated. you can see in the picture where that wire was attached [image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just get a new cable? It's not like they're expensive.

Comment: AFAIK the cable on the Switch power supply is hardwired.

Comment: Nintendo Switch uses USB Power Delivery, so it might be the CC line.

Answer (score 1):

A5/CC1-VCON. It's for the upstream device to negotiate 5v or 15v.